# child window blinking

Tags: winapi, user-interface

My application is dll which is injected into 3rd party GUI application. There dll creates child window containing few controls on the main window of the application. The problem is that my window and its controls blink when the main window is redrawn. I've already read many articles about similar problems but could not fix it. Here is some code

```
hwndContainer = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_TOPMOST, PANEL_CLASS_NAME, "", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 0, 0, width, height, hwnd, 0, g_hInstance, cd );
CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_TOPMOST, "button", "Click me", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, x, y, w, h, hwndContainer, 0, 0, 0 );

...

case WM_PAINT:
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint( hwndPanel, &ps );
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect( hwndPanel, &r );

    SelectObject( hdc, hpenBorder );
    SelectObject( hdc, GetStockObject( NULL_BRUSH ) );

    RoundRect( hdc, 0, 0, r.right, r.bottom, 5, 5 );

    EndPaint( hwndPanel, &ps ); 
    return 0;
```

I tried adding WS_CLIPCHILDREN to the main window style, processed WM_PAINT of the main window etc. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your container window erase its background in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND`?  This is a common cause of flicker.

Comment: Another thought.  If you add a short delay (e.g. `Sleep(500);`) before and after each background erasure and paint you can often see exactly what painting is happening and hence where the flicker is coming from.

Comment: Does your CreateWindow occur on another thread to the main UI thread? Win32 doesn't normally like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may give WS_CLIPSIBLINGS a try... It's been a long time since I've done anything with window styles directly but I seem to remember this style required to help reduce redraw flicker in non-top level windows. Good luck.

Comment: Also, WS_CLIPCHILDREN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx